# Installing php7 on alpine: missing libcrypto and libssl

Tags: alpine-linux, php7

I tried to setup a LEMP stack over Alpine GNU/Linux Distribution running on a VM **WITHOUT** docker.

Then I tried to install the `php7-mysqli` over via community repositories with:

```
sudo apk add php7-mysqli
```

But I got the following errors:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  so:libcrypto.so.43 (missing):
    required by: php7-openssl-7.2.5-r0[so:libcrypto.so.43] php7-openssl-7.2.5-r0[so:libcrypto.so.43]
  so:libssl.so.45 (missing):
    required by: php7-openssl-7.2.5-r0[so:libssl.so.45] php7-openssl-7.2.5-r0[so:libssl.so.45]
```

I have installed `libressl` but the errror still persists. Any idea why that happens? Keep in mind I have set to the repositories to the community's one:

```
http://dl-2.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
```

## Edit 1:

I followed the instructions mentioned in https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-install-php-7-fpm-on-alpine-linux/

## Edit 2:

I tried to install `libressl2.6-libcrypto-2.6.3-r0` via the following command:

```
sudo apk add libressl2.6-libcrypto-2.6.3-r0
```

And I got the following output:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libressl2.6-libcrypto-2.6.3-r0 (missing):
    required by: world[libressl2.6-libcrypto-2.6.3-r0]
```

If I try to install the `libressl` package I get the following response:

```
sudo apk add libressl
(1/2) Installing libressl2.6-libtls (2.6.3-r0)
(2/2) Installing libressl (2.6.3-r0)
Executing busybox-1.27.2-r8.trigger
OK: 119 MiB in 53 packages
```

And the problem still remains.

Also the I tried to install `libressl2.7-libcrypto` via:

```
sudo apk add libressl2.7-libcrypto
```

And I got the following errors:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  libressl2.7-libcrypto (missing):
    required by: world[libressl2.7-libcrypto]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to install:

`libressl2.7-libcrypto`

That package provides both of the files that are missing.

Comment: I tries to install it via `sudo apk add libressl2.7-libcrypto` and I got some errors. I updated the initial post in order to have an easy to read and complete way of my steps.

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Nasir Riley is good but you also have to change your `/etc/apk/repositories` to replace `v3.7` to `edge` that's the first file I change if I want to use latest edge Alpine.

After that you can install `libressl2.7-libcrypto` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

To install the library with a single command:

```
apk add libressl3.1-libcrypto --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main/ --allow-untrusted
```